# IBM Quantum Computing Pulse Control

Tags: qiskit

Does any body know if there is a free IBM quantum computer that supports Pulse Control? All of the ones I see don't support it.

Answer (score 1):

Pulse gate was introduced to replace the old Pulse programs in December 2021.

[image: pulse gates IBM Quantum product updates]

See more details here: https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits_advanced/06_building_pulse_schedules.html

As far as I am aware, all systems in the open provider support pulse gates. You can see how to use pulse gate here: https://qiskit.org/documentation/tutorials/circuits_advanced/05_pulse_gates.html and this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CcB6nRQNB7Y